# How to set custom fields for a user on PocketBase

Tags: go, pocketbase

I am using a PocketBase backend with only email/password auth, and I've added a couple of custom fields to my Users "collection". A user has the following values:

- id
- email
- username (written as profile.username on PB)
- profileImage (written as profile.profileImage on PB)
- created
- updated

Due to project necessities I am consuming the API with a go client, and creating a user as follows:

```golang
func CreateUser(...) (...) {
    user := models.User{
        UserId:          stringUserid,
        Email:           "fake@mail.com",
        Username:        username,
        Password:        stringUserid + "_" + username,
        PasswordConfirm: stringUserid + "_" + username,
        Profile: models.UserProfile{
            Username: username,
            ProfileImage: profileImage
        },
    }

    jsonBody, errorMarshal := json.Marshal(user)
    if errorMarshal != nil {
        return "", errorMarshal
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(BackendURL+"/api/users", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonBody))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
}
```

Where models.User + models.UserProfile is declared as follows:

```golang
type User struct {
    UserId          string      `json:"userId"`
    Email           string      `json:"email"`
    Profile         UserProfile `json:"profile"`
    Password        string      `json:"password"`
    PasswordConfirm string      `json:"passwordConfirm"`
}

type UserProfile struct {
    Username     string `json:"username"`
    ProfileImage string `json:"profileImage"`
}
```

When sending the POST request it does indeed create a new user to the collection, but it doesn't seem to set the username and profileImage values to what I'm sending as JSON.
I do know that it would be recommended to use the pre-built JavaScript/Dart packages when using PocketBase, but for my project necessities, I can only use Go.
I've also tried using the following struct for the User type:

```golang
type User struct {
    UserId          string      `json:"userId"`
    Email           string      `json:"email"`
    Username        string      `json:"username"`
    Password        string      `json:"password"`
    PasswordConfirm string      `json:"passwordConfirm"`
}
```

Is it actually possible to set custom fields this way?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new auth collection? https://pocketbase.io/docs/collections/#auth-collection

Comment: Do you have a related collection for profile info, say `user_profiles`, i.e. userId, username, profileImage? I think the problem is that pocketbase doesn't know what to do with the nested profile object.

I'm with @DSSO21, look into auth collections, as they support for both of the additional fields you need.